# Expose Kafka to outside world in dcos

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka, marathon, dcos

I'm running Kafka in DCOS. I successfully configured several Kafka producers within the DCOS.

Now, I dont know how to connect a Kafka producer running **outside** of the DCOS; I have read that marathon-lb might help, but cannot really understand or find any good example of that. Also, any pointer to some VirtualIP setup to allow connection from outside world will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Highlight on "outside" which is the only problem. Also expanded VIP to VirtualIP for people to understand.

Comment: How do you connect to *any service* from outside DCOS? In other words, this isn't exactly a Kafka question other than which ports you expose

Comment: No @cricket_007 , there is something special about Kafka on Mesos, If you run any service in the bridge mode, you can expose that service to the external world using the marathon-lb. The Kafka doesn't run in the Bridge mode, rather it runs in the Host Mode.